# Exe program with javascript code

Tags: javascript, exe

I need an executable program (and need it running all day) in which when you press certain key codes (like ctr+alt+C) in any moment and window, the program do something.

I have tried with jsc (compiling it from cmd) but im getting this:

```
  accesos.js(8,26) : error JS1004: ';' was expected
  accesos.js(3,1) : error JS1135: The variable 'document' it's not declared
```

And here is the code:

```
var ctrlmod = 0;
var shiftmod = 0;
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(eventK) {
    if(eventK.keyCode == 17) {
        ctrlmod = 1;
    }
    if(ctrlmod == 1){
        if(eventK.keyCode == 16) {
            shiftmod = 1;
        }
        if(shiftmod == 1){
            if(eventK.keyCode == 67){
                alert('c');
                ctrlmod = 0;
                shiftmod = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    if((ctrlmod == 1 || shiftmod == 1) && eventK.keyCode != 17 && eventK.keyCode != 16){
        ctrlmod = 0;
        shiftmod = 0;
    }
});
```

Is there anything I can do to make this work?

Thanks

Comment: The second error is because `document` only exists when you run Javascript in a browser.

Comment: And how can I get a keyboard event without a browser?

Comment: You need to use your operating system's method for defining hotkeys.

Comment: If it's something simple and for Windows, consider using AutoIt or AutoHotKey

Comment: I would switch to node.js, attaching event handlers to the standard input is possible there as well as getting a standalone executable out of your javascript code.

Comment: afaik, you can't use jsc to make something to catch system-wide keypresses. only by using a visible form can keys be captured, and setting up forms in jsc-based scripts is painful to say the least.

Comment: @WiktorZychla: node.js won't be able to capture key presses, except on a command line where it's running.

Comment: Interested in this question, although I doubt you'll find a way, this isn't node's niche. favorited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I tried with AHK (AutoHotKey) and it solved my problem, I hope it work for anyone interested.